# Tourist visa to Costa Rica as a Filipino?

Tags: tourist-visas, filipino-citizens, costa-rica

I'm a Filipino and presently working here in Qatar.

I want to visit Costa Rica -  what are the requirements of getting a tourist visa for that country?

Answer (score 2):

It does not matter where you are currently living, what matters is which passport you hold.  Assuming you hold a passport from the Philippines, you do not need a visa to enter Costa Rica:

> VISA REQUIREMENT: none
>
> LENGTH OF STAY: maximum of 30 days
>
> All adults and children require the following documents to enter Costa
> Rica:
>
> - A valid passport. The passport has to be valid for at least 3
>   months after arrival date to Costa Rica.
> - A return ticket to exit Costa
>   Rica (either to return to your country or to go to another country).

From here: http://www.costarica-embassy.org/?q=node/49

Answer (score 2):

No visa required according to the following website. You can be there for up to 30 days.

http://costarica.com/visa/

Comment: Consider including the relevant parts of that website for a more complete answer, we typically discourage link only replies